# Static duck typing in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, duck-typing, static-polymorphism

C++ has some sort of duck typing for types given by template parameters. We have no idea what type `DUCK1` and `DUCK2` will be, but as long as they can `quack()`, it will compile and run:

```
template <class DUCK1, class DUCK2>
void let_them_quack(DUCK1* donald, DUCK2* daisy){
  donald->quack();
  daisy->quack();
}
```

But it's a bit inconvenient to write. When I do absolutely not care what actual types `DUCK1` and `DUCK2` are but rather want to fully use the idea of duck typing, then I would like to have something sligthly different than above:

1. I'd like to omit writing a template parameter list that is repetitive and mostly meaningless (Just imagine what would happen if there are 7 ducks...)
2. I'd like to make it a bit more explicit that the types are never used and that it's only the interface that matters.
3. I'd like to have sort of an interface annotation/check. Make somehow clear what interface is expected behind the type. (That's, however, a bit in contrast of duck typing.)

**Does C++ offer any features to achieve one or more of the 3 ideas?**

(I know that virtual inheritance is the method of choice in most cases to implement such patterns, but the question here is specifically about the case of static polymorphism.)

Comment: `concept Duckable`... coming to you in a [TS](http://wg21.link/p0121) near you.

Comment: Well it is not standard yet but hopefully C++17 will allow us to use [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) as a function parameter to make this easier.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not on the docket for C++17, right? Maybe we'll see it in 2020. :(

Comment: @erip: You can ask your vendor whether they implement the TS. I think GCC and Clang do, or will do soon.

Comment: @KerrekSB I meant as a part of the standard. I'm trying to write more and more standard-compliant code. :)

Comment: @NathanOliver Writing auto in a normal function is part of the concepts TS. Also: the concept TS will make it into the standard eventually and it is already implemented in GCC 6. So unless you need C++17 compliant code you could probably use it.

Comment: @KlemensMorgenstern Which is why I said it is not standard yet.  I try not to suggest not standard methods unless the OP specifically asks for it.

Comment: @NathanOliver: OP is an adult, so there's no reason to hide non-standard code ;-) Answers containing non-standard-code are perfectly fine, as long as you clearly mention the non-standard-status. As OP you should be able to decide by yourself whether you use it or not.

Answer (score 11):

Concerning questions 1 and 2: since C++14 you can omit explicit `template <typename ...` boilerplate and use `auto`, but only in lambdas:

```
auto let_them_quack = [] (auto & donald, auto & daisy){
    donald.quack();
    daisy.quack();
};
```

(yes, I prefer references to pointers). GCC allows to do so in usual functions as an extension.

For the question 3, what you are talking about are called *concepts*. They existed in C++ for a long time, but only as a documentational term. Now the **Concepts TS** is in progress, allowing you to write something like

```
template<typename T>
concept bool Quackable = requires(T a) {
    a.quack();
};

void let_them_quack (Quackable & donald, Quackable & daisy);
```

Note that it is not yet C++, only a technical specification in progress. GCC 6.1 already seems to support it, though. Implementations of concepts and constraints using current C++ are possible; you can find one in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm).

Comment: AFAIK your top example only works for lambdas not free functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver I thought so too, but both ideone with C++14 and my local gcc accepted it. Seems to be an extension, I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Yes it is a gcc extension.

Comment: I think it's the only answer so far which hits the intent of the question. Too bad that these ideas are not yet standard...

Comment: Always always always compile your gcc code with `-pedantic` :)

Answer (score 5):

> I'd like to omit writing a template parameter list that is repetitive
>   and mostly meaningless (Just imagine what would happen if there are 7
>   ducks...)

For that you could use variadic templates and do something like the following:

```
template<typename DUCK>
void let_them_quack(DUCK &&d) {
  d.quack();
}

template<typename DUCK, typename... Args>
void let_them_quack(DUCK &&d, Args&& ...args) {
  d.quack();
  let_them_quack(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fefe9eb9dfcf5f80)

Comment: Why are you saying `d.quack()` twice?

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry, can you make it a little bit clearer? Do you mean the trivial step of the recursion?

Answer (score 1):

#2 and #3 are sort of taken care of by the fact that the code will not compile, and throw a compilation error, if the given classes don't implement the interface. You could also make this formal:

```
class duck {

public:
   virtual void quack()=0;
};
```

Then declare the parameters to the function as taking a pointer to a duck. Your classes will have to inherit from this class, making the requirements for `let_them_quack()` crystal clear.

As far as #1 goes, variadic templates can take care of this.

```
void let_them_quack()
{
}

template <typename ...Args>
void let_them_quack(duck* first_duck, Args && ...args) {
  first_duck->quack();
  let_them_quack(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: I agree with Kerrek and I furthermore think that the solution does neither clarify anything nor is it easier to read/write...

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to make it look preetier with concept (not yet in standard - but very close):

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Vjy2U6BPbsTuSK3u

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>concept bool ItQuacks(){
    return requires (T a) {
        { a.quack() } -> void;
    };
}

void let_them_quack2(ItQuacks* donald, ItQuacks* daisy){
  donald->quack();
  daisy->quack();
}

struct DisneyDuck {
    void quack(){ std::cout << "Quack!";}
};

struct RegularDuck {
    void quack(){ std::cout << "Quack2!";}
};

struct Wolf {
    void woof(){ std::cout << "Woof!";}
};

int main() {
    DisneyDuck q1, q2;
    let_them_quack2(&q1, &q2);

    RegularDuck q3, q4;
    let_them_quack2(&q3, &q4);    

    //Wolf w1, w2;
    //let_them_quack2(&w1, &w2);    // ERROR: constraints not satisfied
}
```

output:

```
 Quack!Quack!Quack2!Quack2!
```

As you can see, you will be able to: `omit writing a template parameter list`, ItQuacks is quite explicit so `types are never used and that it's only the interface that matters` takes place. This `I'd like to have sort of an interface annotation/check.` also takes place, concept use will also give you meaningfull error message.

Comment: The syntax changed a bit since this was written: mostly removing `bool` and adding `auto` to the function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

We only need to write one version of the function:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename... Quackers>
void let_them_quack(Quackers&& ...quackers) {
  using expand = int[];

  void(expand { 0, (std::forward<Quackers>(quackers).quack(), 0)... });
}

struct Duck {
  void quack() {}
};

int main()
{
  Duck a, b, c;
  let_them_quack(a, b, c, Duck());
}
```